# clear certain text fields in tabbed form

Tags: javascript, html

I have this tabbed form with four different text fields and two similar submit buttons. The form is used by patrons to login to their library account. A problem arises when someone tries to login using the text fields in one tab, is unsuccessful, and proceeds to login using the text fields in the other tab. When patrons attempt to login both ways, the information from their last unsuccessful attempt is not cleared out. When switching back and forth between the two different login areas, how do I clear user entered information?

```
function tabSwitch(new_tab, new_content) {
 document.getElementById('ldap_login').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('barcode_login').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById(new_content).style.display='block';

 document.getElementById('ldap_tab').className='';
 document.getElementById('barcode_tab').className='';
 document.getElementById(new_tab).className='active';
}

<div id=" " class="tabbed_area">
 <form name="patform" method="POST">

<ul id="tabs">
 <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('ldap_tab', 'ldap_login');" id="ldap_tab" class="active">Active students, faculty, and staff</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('barcode_tab', 'barcode_login');" id="barcode_tab">Community, alumni, emeriti, and others</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ldap_login" class="content">
 Clemson Username: <br />
 <input type="text" name="extpatid" id="extpatid" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
 Your iRoar, Blackboard, etc., username <br/>
 Password:* <br />
 <input name="extpatpw" id="extpatpw" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
 *Passwords cannot contain the special characters < and >. <br /><br />
 <input type="image" src="/screens/pat_submit.gif" border="0" name="" value="submit">
</div>

<div id="barcode_login" class="content">
 Last Name: <br />
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
 For example, type "Smith." <br />
 Barcode: <br />
 <input name="code" id="code" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
 Type the letter plus 10 digit number located on the back of your TigerOne ID card (or 9 digit number plus "1" for old library cards).<br /><br />
 <input type="image" src="/screens/pat_submit.gif" border="0" name="" value="submit">
</div>

 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your 2 tabs into their own forms. That way the submits will only take the inputs from their respective tabs and ignore whatever is on the other tab.

```
<div id="ldap_login" class="content">
 <form>
     Clemson Username: <br />
     <input type="text" name="extpatid" id="extpatid" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
     Your iRoar, Blackboard, etc., username <br/>
     Password:* <br />
     <input name="extpatpw" id="extpatpw" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
     *Passwords cannot contain the special characters < and >. <br /><br />
     <input type="image" src="/screens/pat_submit.gif" border="0" name="" value="submit">
 </form>
</div>
```

Etc..